# Enum Type: Int / Expected identifier after comma in enum 'case' declaration

Tags: swift, enums

I have a model for my `UISegmentedControl`. 
I have an error on my `enum` and I don't know what it is.

In my `SegmentedControl` I want to have for : 
Index 0 = 1(Int)
Index 1 = 2(Int).....

My code and my View on the link.

[image]

Comment: Post code as text, not as images or links to images. For a good reference on the Swift language use [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)

Comment: first, you may need to start with Swift language's basics: [Naming Constants and Variables](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need commas in your enum. If you want an Int enum you should write

```
enum MamsEntreeGout: Int {
   case firstValue           = 1
   case secondValue          = 2
   case thirdValue           = 3
   case fourthValue          = 4
 }
```

And the same for the other enum.

Enjoy

Comment: The commas are not the problem (`enum Foo { case a, b, c, d }` is valid Swift).

Comment: Yes I only mean that commas are not necessary but thanks for specify.

Answer (score 0):

In `Swift` you cannot directly define an `Int` value as an `enum's case`, i.e. the below `enum` is invalid.

```
enum MamsEntreeGout {
    case 1
}
```

Instead you should create an `enum's cases` with same `syntax` as of the `variables`, i.e

```
enum MamsEntreeGout {
    case first
}
```

In `Swift`, `enum's cases` doesn't have any `default values` like in other languages. So if you want to associate the `cases` with any `value`, you must specify a `Raw Type`, i.e.

```
enum MamsEntreeGout: Int {
    case first
}
```

In the above code, `Int` is the `Raw Type` of `enum MamsEntreeGout`.

> When integers are used for raw values, the implicit value for each
>   case is one more than the previous case. If the first case doesn’t
>   have a value set, its value is 0.

So, there is no need to define the `values` for each `case` if the `enum` has `Raw Type` as `Int`.

So, you can define your `enums` like:

```
enum MamsEntreeGout: Int {
   case first = 1, second, third, fourth
}
```

`, separated cases` are definitely allowed in `Swift`.

To access the `Int` value of any of the `cases` of `enum` use **`rawValue`** with the `case name`, i.e.

```
MamsEntreeGout.third.rawValue
```

Answer (score 0):

The identifiers in an enum can not be or start with a number, it has to be a letter (a-z, A-Z) an underscore or some unicode characters, see https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#grammar_identifier-head

So

```
enum bad {
    case 1, 2word, 3.0
}
```

is not allowed but

```
enum good {
    case a1, _2, treedotzero
}
```

will work fine